# Unable to load main class when compiling and running a java file using C++

Tags: java, c++, api, twitter, twitter4j

I've been trying to compile and execute a java file from C++ but I am currently getting this error. The java file works fine when executed separately in java.

This is the error code received:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TwitterDataCrawler
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TwitterDataCrawler
```

In my C++ file:

(TwitterDataCrawler.java is the file i wish to run \ twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar is the twitter API that is required to run)

```
int main()
{
    system("javac -cp twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar TwitterDataCrawler.java");
    system("java -cp TwitterDataCrawler.java TwitterDataCrawler arg1");
    return 0;
}
```

The structure of my java file looks something like this:

```
public class TwitterDataCrawler {
    public TwitterDataCrawler() {
    }   
    public static void viewAccident(int x) throws TwitterException, IOException{
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException {
            viewAccident(5000);
    }
}
```

I have to call the public static void main function from within the class TwitterDataCrawler. I assume that since the class does contains a main function, targeting the class with an argument should work. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this in C++?? And you should understand the very basics of java commandline stuff before automating things (Hint: you are searching for your compiled class in a directory named "TwitterDataCrawler.java"

Comment: this seems to be not a problem of calling `system` but of the parameters you pass to it. Do this commands work if you type them by hand on the command line?

Comment: I see what you mean. @GyroGearless
Changing the code to:
system("java -cp TwitterDataCrawler");

Gave me this message:
https://imgur.com/a/wNwcolI
Am i still lacking something? Yes, this is my first time meddling with java commandline, I should have read up on it first before I began.

Comment: Then go ahead and check how to compile java code from the commandline, your updated command tries to invoke java without a main class, just setting a classpath to an invalid file called "TwitterDataCrawler". Apart from that I'm with Gyro: Why the hell are you using C++ to invoke java? If you just want a simple program that automates this process for you, you can just add the shell commands into a bash or batch file and run that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
system(javac -cp twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar TwitterDataCrawler.java);
system(java -cp .;twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar TwitterDataCrawler);
```

Since the class created from using javac is dependent on a jar API(both residing in the same directory), ".;twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar" is included in order to execute TwitterDataCrawler.